# How does dispatch_time work when iPhone becomes in background state?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

```
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
```

When using this method and pressing the home button on an iphone, the *delay* would no longer work or be valid. Instead what happens is when going back to my app, the **closure** that was suppose to be triggered after "10 seconds" would only happen when coming back to the app. Regardless if i went back to the app after 1 hour or 10 seconds.

How would i make the triggered **closure** work after the *delay* in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the home button your app will transition to the background state and if nothing keeps it in that state, it will transition to the suspended state in which no code will run.

One way to keep your app running in the background is to use background tasks.

`let taskId = UIApplication.sharedApplication.beginBackgroundTask(..)`

You can then end the background task after your code runs:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication.endBackgroundTask(taskId)`

This will allow the app to go back into the suspended state.

Comment: how would i go about entering the function that i want to run in this method? there is only "beginBackgroundTaskWithName(name:expressionHandler:)"

Comment: Use "beginBackgroundTaskWithName(name:expressionHandler:)". Pass in a name which can be any string and a closure which will run if the background task is expired by the system.